# Custom iterator: how to correctly handle distance calculation and equality comparison between a and b if the behavior of those differe

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17

I wrote a class `PointerIterator` which provides a random access iterator for arrays. I know pointers itself are valid iterators but my implementation allows to specify a *unit*. This *unit* specifies the step that is taken by each increment or decrement. The reason behind is to enable i.e. iteration over a row in an **n** x **m** matrix where the matrix is stored as a single array in row major order.

However, because *unit* is unknown at compile time it has to be specified as a ctor argument at runtime. This leads to the problem that two iterators of the same type can yield different behaviors (if *unit* is different from each other).

## Example

Let **m** be a 4x4 matrix represented by a single array (in row major order).

```
auto rowSize = 4;
auto colSize = 4;
auto m = new int[rowSize * colSize];

// m is somehow filled with increasing numbers, like:

  0   1   2   3    
  4   5   6   7
  8   9  10  11
 12  13  14  15
```

To iterate over the first row of **A**, two PointerIterators are created (to mark the beginning and end of the range)

```
auto begin = makePointerIterator(m, 1);
auto end = begin + rowSize;
```

where `makePointerIterator(pointer, unit)` creates a PointerIterator for the pointer *pointer* with step *unit*.

With `begin` and `end` from above, we can use a for loop to print the first row, like:

```
for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it)
    cout << std::setw(3) << *it << " ";
```

which yields

```
  0   1   2   3
```

To iterate over the first column, we have to change `begin` and `end` to

```
auto begin = makePointerIterator(m, rowSize);
auto end = begin + colSize;
```

Each increment (i.e. `operator++`) causes the pointer to step forward by `rowSize` which points to the next element in the column.

Printing the column can now be done by the same for loop above, which now yields:

```
  0   4   8  12
```

## The problem

In order to make a [valid](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) random access iterator, I have to provide (amongst others)

```
difference_type operator-(PointerIterator other) const;
bool operator==(PointerIterator other) const;
bool operator!=(PointerIterator other) const;
```

Lets say I have two PointerIterators `a` and `b` where `a.unit == 1` and `b.unit == 2` which means `a` increases the pointer by 1 and `b` increases (or decreases) the pointer by 2 at each increment (or decrement).

How do I have to implement the 3 functions above while keeping the iterator standard conform?

The possible solutions that came in my mind were:

1. Preemptively check if `a.unit == b.unit` and if not, throw an exception.
2. Use always `a.unit` (which is at the left hand side of the operators), which would cause that `a == b` may not be equal to `b == a`.

## Edit

I put the implementation on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192195/custom-c-random-access-iterator-for-pointers-to-arrays) in case someone is interested in it.

Comment: Iterators of the same type but with different units can be treated the same way as iterators of the same type but pointing into different containers. That is, it's the programmer's responsibility to make sure the units are the same, otherwise it's UB to mix the iterators.

Comment: `auto end = m + colSize;` surely you mean `auto end = begin + colSize;`

Comment: @YSC then you are confined to units known at compile time, which is too limiting.

Comment: @YSC I cannot know the unit at compile time and thus not have different types. If I would do so, the iterator of a 3x3 matrix would be a different type to the iterator of a 4x4 matrix, which leads to having different types for each matrix size which is impossible to implement.

Comment: @KillzoneKid thanks, fixed it

Comment: @YSC Imagine I have a pointer (created at runtime) that represents a matrix of some shape. In order to use different types, I have to instanciate a template for each possible matrix size. But the matrix size is only known at runtime so I cannot instanciate the template.

Comment: That answers my question, it is a requirement.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but "the matrix is stored as a single pointer" misstates what's going on. The matrix is stored as **an array** which, I gather, is **accessed through** a single pointer. A pointer is not an array, and an array is not a pointer. Keep those two distinct in your mind: that will save you a lot of grief.

Comment: @PeteBecker you are correct. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterators of the same type but with different units can be treated the same way as iterators of the same type but pointing into different containers. That is, it's the programmer's responsibility to make sure the units are the same, otherwise it's Undefined Behaviour to mix (compare or subtract) the iterators.

Answer (score 0):

First, undefined behavior is your friend.  Have "safe" operations that throw or use algebraic error types to indicate a mismatch, but the `==` operation can simply make the result undefined, like comparing iterators of different containers are.

Second, consider doing this:

```
template<class Unit, class=void>
struct default_unit_value {};

template<class Unit,
  std::enable_if_t< std::is_integral<Unit>{} >
>
struct default_unit_value:std::integral_constant<Unit, 1> {};

template<class T, class Unit=std::ptrdiff_t>
struct PointerIterator {
  PointerIterator(T* p = nullptr, Unit u = default_unit_value<Unit>::value):
    ptr(p), unit(u)
  {}
private:
  T* ptr;
  Unit unit; // actually use a compressed pair, in case Unit is stateless
};
```

this permits compile-time constant unit sizes to be used and mismatch errors in those cases to be checked at compile time.

```
auto begin = makePointerIterator<1>(m);
auto end = begin + rowSize;

constexpr rowSize = 4;
auto begin = makePointerIterator<rowSize>(m);
auto end = begin + colSize;
```

meanwhile, runtime variable stride is still available.

In a large number of cases you do know the element stride distance at compile time.  Telling the compiler explicitly will generate better code.

Comment: I get your point, but the main usage of this class (in my case) is, to provide an easy way to iterate over the adjacency matrix of a directed graph. And in this case I do know the matrix size only at run time. I just generalized the implementation to make it reusable.